# Create new File vs createTempFile

Tags: java, android, file

I want to create a file and set the URI to my imageView like this:

```
// this code will work, but it will generate a random number at the end of my file
f = File.createTempFile(image, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, getAlbumDir());

// this will result with an exception at imageView.setImageURI()
f = new File(getAlbumDir(), image + JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX);

imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(f));
```

here's the exception:

```
01-02 15:19:06.575: W/ImageView(26097): Unable to open content: file:///storage/sdcard0/dcim/myapp/20000102_151858_.jpg
01-02 15:19:06.575: W/ImageView(26097): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/dcim/myapp/20000102_151858_.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Since I want to get rid of the random number at the end of my image name. How can I make `new File()`work?

Comment: The way you are creating a file is wrong

Comment: Firstly  check example to create file

Comment: what am I doing wrong with creating the file?

Comment: `getAlbumDir()` points to a valid path? Does this point to an existing folder?

Comment: yes it does; `createTempFile` works without any problems with the same arguments

Comment: Do you have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make new File()work?

It does work, but it doesn't create files on secondary storage. It just creates a `File` object in memory. So, n the second case you *aren't* creating a file at all.

If you want to create an empty file, call `f.createNewFile()`. You probably don't want to do that: you probably want to put some content into it, via a `new FileOutputStream(f).`